# How to fetch image URL from Fresco's SimpleDraweeView?

Tags: android, url, fresco, imageurl

Get Image URL from **Fresco SimpleDraweeView**.

I have recyclerView items with EditText and SimpleDraweeView, also have on the button on my activity. on button click, I want to get whole recyclerview items data into ArrayList.

**Here is the code which written on button click and  i successfully got editText data except SimpleDraweeView URL.**

```
        ArrayList<ContactUs> getContactUsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < getContactUsArrayList.size(); i++) {
        View view = rvContact.getChildAt(i);
        EditText etName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etName);
        EditText etMobile = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etMobile);
        SimpleDraweeView sdvImage = (SimpleDraweeView) view.findViewById(R.id.sdvImage);

        String strName = etName.getText().toString();
        String strNumber = etMobile.getText().toString();
        String strImgUrl = ""; //what is the property?


    }
```

What is the property for getting URL from SimpleDraweeView?

Comment: how you are pushing data in recyclerview?

Comment: load data from API and push data to adapter then i try to get whole items data on the button click from activity

Comment: you can save the url from the API and inside the for loop use the same using index number. Currently, SimpleDraweeView doesn't support direct url.

Comment: okay that means,
get specific item data based on position, correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: yes. save the urls in another list and use it later

Comment: okay i will try

Comment: @RahulKhurana Thanks for the idea.
i have done using loop and  i got whole item object.

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse your image URL like this.

```
SimpleDraweeView simpleDraweeView = 
(SimpleDraweeView)findViewById(R.id.simpleviewid);

Uri imageuri = Uri.parse("YOUR IMAGE URL");
simpleDraweeView.setImageURI(imageuri);
```

Make sure to initialize fresco before `setContentView()`, and width and height in XML file of simpleDraweeView must not be wrap content. Try this.

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I understood your question but there is not any properties to get the image in the form of String but you can achieve this by something like below. I assume if you set your image in layout correctly.

```
Drawable drawable = draweeView.getBackground();
        Bitmap bitmap = draweeView.getDrawingCache();
        Drawable drawable1 = draweeView.getHierarchy().getTopLevelDrawable();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: As i see above comments you should have to save the list of load data or which list you have passed in the adapter to load the data in the recycle view, you can use the same list to get the image url according to the position in onBindViewHolder method.

Answer (score 0):

***I got Solution based on Answers and comments***

**What i have done**

***Replace This code***

```
        ArrayList<ContactUs> getContactUsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < getContactUsArrayList.size(); i++) {
        View view = rvContact.getChildAt(i);
        EditText etName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etName);
        EditText etMobile = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etMobile);
        SimpleDraweeView sdvImage = (SimpleDraweeView) view.findViewById(R.id.sdvImage);

        String strName = etName.getText().toString();
        String strNumber = etMobile.getText().toString();
        String strImgUrl = ""; //what is the property?


    }
```

***With This code***

```
   ArrayList<ContactUs> getContactUsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ContactUs contactUs;
    for (int i = 0; i < getContactUsArrayList.size(); i++) {
        contactUs = getContactUsArrayList.get(i);//Here i got whole object.
        String strName = contactUs.getUserName();
        String strNumber = contactUs.getUserMobile();
        String strImgUrl=contactUs.getImagePath();

    }
```